# Sentinel Emulator 2007 Error

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, emulator, dongle

In windows 10 64 bit, when I click "Start Service" after installing the driver, I get an error message " Error 1275".

[image: Error]

However, I could start the service without any error message in windows 7 32 bit. I would like to use an application for which this service is required to be run.

Could you please help me solve this problem?